# JWT Roles Are Missing From Token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, entra

One of my customer is using my app that requires Mail.ReadWrite, Directory.Read.All, User.Read.All

```
 def url_for_service(user)
  [
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?',
    "client_id=#{ENV['APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID']}",
    "&state=#{user.token}",
    '&response_type=code',
    '&response_mode=query',
    "&redirect_uri=#{ENV['APPLICATION_REDIRECT_URI']}",
    "&scope=#{ENV['AZURE_APPLICATION_SCOPE']}",
    "&prompt=select_account"
  ].join
end

def url_for_admin(state)
  [
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    'organizations',
    '/v2.0/adminconsent?',
    "client_id=#{ENV['AZURE_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID']}",
    "&state=#{state}",
    "&redirect_uri=#{ENV['AZURE_ADMIN_APPLICATION_REDIRECT_URI']}",
    "&scope=#{ENV['AZURE_APPLICATION_SCOPE']}"
  ].join
end
```

its working fine for all customers but for one customer i was getting following error when fetching users list

```
{'error': {'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied', 'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', 'innerError': {'date': '2024-03-05T14:23:22', 'request-id': '27ae1e9d-8ded-454e-93d6-01b70063d8ce', 'client-request-id': '27ae1e9d-8ded-454e-93d6-01b70063d8ce'}}}
```

when debugging it i realized the roles were missing in their JWT Token, even though the user which authenticated the external app is a global administrator.

What could be reason of roles not appearing inside JWT token ?

Comment: Could you attach the screenshot of the API permissions in the Azure AD application?